# How to adjust the Screen size in ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I developed a web page in ASP.Net (C#). In my machine screen resolution is 1280*1024, i designed according to this resolution, so when i run the page i have no problems in viewing it.

But when i run the page in someother machine with different screen resolutions like (1024*768), there are some changes in the allignment of the text boxes and labels in the page.

May i know how to set the page according to different screen resolutions automatically? I need to view the page same as i look in my machine. How to do that? Can anyone please guide me to do that?

I'm using a MasterPage aswell.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

When design form, you have to use `width` as a percentage instead of a fixed `width`.

I think you have used something like...

```
<table style="width: 1000px">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 1000px">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 1000px">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

when you need to use something like...

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 50%">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50%">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: May i know where to use the Percentage for width?

Answer (score 1):

using some grid CSS will help you to achieve that: Check BlueprintCSS http://www.blueprintcss.org/